# EXTJS, how to escape special character?

Tags: javascript, extjs

In the EXTJS, how to escape special character ?

for example, compiler is complaining showDetail('{1}') , how to escape the '' ?

Thanks

```
 return Ext.String.format(
            '{0} <a href="#" onclick="showDetail('{1}');">detail</a>',
            value,            
            record.getReportId()            
        );
```

Comment: Using a powerful library but generating HTML with `onclick` attributes and `href="#"`? :(

Comment: what do you mean ? have a better way ?

Comment: [`addListener`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.EventManager) and either using a `<button>` or actually linking somewhere useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the standard `\`. Place it before `'` like so `\'`.

```
    return Ext.String.format(
        '{0} <a href="#" onclick="showDetail(\'{1}\');">detail</a>',
        value,            
        record.getReportId()            
    );
```